# how to send ether in hardhat instead of msg.value in remix

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

I have faced a problem during test my contract
i used `msg.value` in remix ide but when i want to test the contract i have faced a problem have to replace `msg.value`

```
/**
     * @dev buy a coffee for contract owner
     * @param _name name of the coffee buyer
     * @param _message A nice message from the coffee buyer
     */
    function buyCoffee(string memory _name, string memory _message)
        public
        payable
    {
        if (msg.value <= 0) {
            revert BUYME_Cannot_buyCoffeeWithZeroEth();
        }
        // create a new memo
        Memo memory memo = Memo(msg.sender, block.timestamp, _name, _message);
        memos.push(memo);
        // emit a log event when new memo is created
        emit NewMemo(msg.sender, block.timestamp, _name, _message);
    }
```

I have called it like that

```
const tip = await hre.ethers.utils.formatEther('1')
  await buyMeACoffee
    .connect(owner)
    .buyCoffee('Med', 'You are the best')
```

when i call it in hardhat i want to pass an amount of ether , **any advice**

Answer (score 2):

In order to send funds to the function being tested you shoul use something like this:

```
contractInstance.testFunction(<any function args>, 
    { value: ethers.utils.parseUnits("1", "ether") });
```

so in your case

```
const tip = { value: hre.ethers.utils.parseEther('1') };
await buyMeACoffee.connect(tipAccount).buyCoffee('Med', 'You are the best', tip)
```

Comment: Thanks alot i have do same thing